# how to check if hard drive is eide or sata with powershell

Tags: powershell, wmi

I like to know if there is any win32 class that can detect if a hard drive is eide or sata. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no straight way to find that. However, you can use the caption property of Win32_DiskDrive and parse it to see if you have a ATA or SCSI disk. On my system, SATA disk has a caption `ST9500420AS ATA Device`.

The way you do this is:

```
Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_DiskDrive | Select Caption, Index
```

You can parse the `Caption` property to find if it contains ATA or SCSI.

Comment: Hi ravikanth. Thanks for your reply. You're always very kind. I forgot to say that I had already checked that class. unluckily, following your advice, my caption is WDC WD5000BEVT-22A0RT0 while index is 0. So it seems that I can't always rely on that class.

Comment: Oh, okay. AFAIK, there is no easy way then. Windows does not provide a way to query for the type of disk. You may have to use manufacturer's API, if available.

Comment: Ok thanks. This is the reason why I didn't find anything even searching on google. Thanks again. Hallo.

Comment: NP. Glad that my answers have been helpful. Wish I could help you with this as well.

Comment: my Caption = WDC WD10JPVX-22JC3T0 ATA Device, Now How to find out is it SATA or IDE, In real it is SATA.

Comment: I have 6 Samsung SSDs in my system (4 * 960, 1 850 Pro, and 1 850 EVO) and the caption is the product name:,"Samsung SSD 850 PRO 2TB", "Samsung SSD 850 EVO 500GB", and "Samsung SSD 960 PRO 512GB". None of these have "ATA Device", at least on my Windows 10 box using powershell, so possibly only older disks or some/all Seagate drives.

Answer (score 9):

As noted in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362199/how-to-check-if-hard-drive-is-eide-or-sata-with-powershell/5362505#5362505) the drive's caption (ie. model name) might include this information you can navigate the WMI objects associations until you get to a device with a more definitive name/caption/other property.

Keeping `devmgmt.msc` open with View | Devices by Connection open while developing will make things easier.

The key to navigating the WMI object graph is ["ASSOCIATORS OF"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384793%28VS.85%29.aspx) queries.

So (using lots of aliases and other shortcuts to make this easier: I would avoid this in something I plan to reuse):

```
gwmi win32_DiskDrive |
  %{gwmi -query "ASSOCIATORS OF {$($_.__RELPATH)} where resultclass = Win32_PnpEntity"}
```

will get the [`Win32_PnpEntity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394353%28VS.85%29.aspx) objects for each disk drive.

Repeating this on the first (for the purposes of exploration) disk drive to another level to find what kind of associations exist:

```
gwmi win32_DiskDrive |
  %{gwmi -query "ASSOCIATORS OF {$($_.__RELPATH)} where resultclass = Win32_PnpEntity" |
    %{gwmi -query "ASSOCIATORS OF {$($_.__RELPATH)}"}} | fl __CLASS,__RELPATH
```

shows a mix of WMI classes:

```
__CLASS   : Win32_SystemDriver
__RELPATH : Win32_SystemDriver.Name="disk"

__CLASS   : Win32_ComputerSystem
__RELPATH : Win32_ComputerSystem.Name="hostname"

__CLASS   : Win32_IDEController
__RELPATH : Win32_IDEController.DeviceID="PCIIDE\\IDECHANNEL\\4&5ECF4F&0&2"

__CLASS   : CIM_DataFile
__RELPATH : CIM_DataFile.Name="c:\\windows\\system32\\drivers\\disk.sys"

__CLASS   : Win32_DiskDrive
__RELPATH : Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID="\\\\.\\PHYSICALDRIVE0"
```

The last of these is just navigating back to the disk drive, and every device is associated with a computer system. But that [`Win32_IDEController`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394155%28VS.85%29.aspx) object looks interesting.

It had a `ProtocolSupported` property with values for different buses, but all instances here are 37 ("IDE"), and there are instances for both the controller channels *and* the controllers:

```
PS[64bit] C:\bin\PowerShell> gwmi win32_idecontroller | ft -auto -wrap caption,description

caption                                  description
-------                                  -----------
ATA Channel 1                            IDE Channel
ATA Channel 0                            IDE Channel
ATA Channel 1                            IDE Channel
Standard AHCI 1.0 Serial ATA Controller  Standard AHCI 1.0 Serial ATA Controller
Standard AHCI 1.0 Serial ATA Controller  Standard AHCI 1.0 Serial ATA Controller
Standard Dual Channel PCI IDE Controller Standard Dual Channel PCI IDE Controller
ATA Channel 0                            IDE Channel
ATA Channel 1                            IDE Channel
ATA Channel 2                            IDE Channel
ATA Channel 3                            IDE Channel
ATA Channel 4                            IDE Channel
ATA Channel 5                            IDE Channel
ATA Channel 0                            IDE Channel
```

So it isn't going to be as easy as getting to a `Win32_IDEController`.

Going back and expanding the `Win32_IDEController` associated with  `Win32_PnpDevice` for my disk:

```
gwmi win32_DiskDrive |
  %{gwmi -query "ASSOCIATORS OF {$($_.__RELPATH)} where resultclass = Win32_PnpEntity" |
    %{gwmi -query "ASSOCIATORS OF {$($_.__RELPATH)}  where resultclass = Win32_IDEController"}} |
  fl Caption,Description
```

```
caption     : ATA Channel 2
description : IDE Channel
```

So that's the SATA channel, will the channel be associated with the controller? And simplifying: the output of a `foreach-object` doesn't need an inner pipeline:

```
gwmi win32_DiskDrive |
  %{gwmi -query "ASSOCIATORS OF {$($_.__RELPATH)} where resultclass = Win32_PnpEntity"} |
  %{gwmi -query "ASSOCIATORS OF {$($_.__RELPATH)}  where resultclass = Win32_IDEController"} |
  %{gwmi -query "ASSOCIATORS OF {$($_.__RELPATH)}  where resultclass = Win32_IDEController"} |
  fl __CLASS,__RELPATH.Caption,Description
```

This finds nothing, but a little exploring (capturing the `__RELPATH` from one query to paste into another to keep pipeline under control) indicates that following the associations:

```
DiskDrive --> PnpDevice --> IDEContoller --> PnpDevice --> IDEController
```

should get the result. Avoiding looping (as the IDEController has two associated PnpDevice objects) is left as an exercise.

Once the true controller is reached, the caption will need to be parsed.

#### The Bad News

Repeating the query for controllers on another system gave three instances of `Standard Dual Channel PCI IDE Controller` despite having *four* controller (1×IDE and 3×SATA), this might be related to the non-trivial mapping due to one running as RAID?

And of course SATA has essentially the same logical (programming) interface as IDE to make new hardware work with software (the same applies with PCI and PCI-Express) means the OS doesn't really need to know.

Comment: Hi Richard. Thanks for all the time you've dedicated me with this detailed answer. I really appreciate it. I've learned something new about wmi and powershell. Thanks again. :)

Answer (score 0):

I know, this queston is a little bit old, but what about using another WMI-Object:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class MSFT_PhysicalDisk -Namespace root\Microsoft\Windows\Storage  | Select FriendlyName, MediaType, BusType
```

The BusType 2 stands for ATAPI, 3 for ATA and 11 means SATA. Some more are USB, SCSI oder SSD. According to Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_ATA) ATA and ATAPI are both parallel interfaces (IDE / EIDE) for harddisks.

The object is available since Windows 7 as far as I know and delivers many interesting values.

Answer (score 0):

@Richard's answer is fantastic, but it's a bit old and dated at this point.

His code can be significantly simplified on newer versions of Powershell (v3+). Further, on Powershell v6+ the old `Get-WmiObject` command is no longer available at all. In both cases, you can use the `Get-CimInstance` command and the `Get-CimAssociatedInstance` command:

```
Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_DiskDrive -KeyOnly |
  Get-CimAssociatedInstance -ResultClassName Win32_PnpEntity -KeyOnly |
  Get-CimAssociatedInstance -ResultClassName Win32_IDEController |
  Select-Object CreationClassName, DeviceID, Caption, Description |
  Format-List
```

`Get-CimInstance` works basically the same as `Get-WmiObject`, though it has improved output in most cases. `Get-CimAssociatedInstance` does all the obnoxious `ASSOCIATORS OF` stuff you used to have to do manually with gwmi.

The `-KeyOnly` parameter tells the commands earlier in the pipeline to on return the unique idenfiers for the objects they return. Since we just want the early commands in the pipeline to identify the hardware items there's no need to have those commands return anything else.

That said,the above is probably unnecessary on newer versions of Powershell that have `Get-Volume`, `Get-Partition`, `Get-PhysicalDisk` or `Get-Disk`. If you're on a newer version of Windows, you can probably just run `Get-PhysicalDisk | Select-Object FriendlyName, BusType`. You can often get much better (though not necessarily perfect) attributes this way.

You can still use the CIM classes, but be aware that [CIM mapping between the different newer CIM storage classes is complicated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/stormgmt/storage-management-api-classes) because it can represent quite complex arrangements, but it helps when you know most of them can go through `MSFT_StorageSubSystem`.

For example this gives you the physical disks associated with drive C:

```
Get-CimInstance -Namespace ROOT/Microsoft/Windows/Storage -ClassName MSFT_Volume -Filter "DriveLetter='C'" -KeyOnly | 
  Get-CimAssociatedInstance -ResultClassName MSFT_StorageSubSystem -KeyOnly |
  Get-CimAssociatedInstance -ResultClassName MSFT_PhysicalDisk |
  Select-Object -Property FriendlyName, SerialNumber, MediaType, BusType, Size, OperationalStatus, ObjectID -Unique
```

Note that the namespace `ROOT/Microsoft/Windows/Storage` must be specified on the first command because the new storage classes are not in the default namespace.

Here, the `-Unique` parameter along with including the `ObjectID` property on the physical disk is helping to ensure that the command is not returning duplicates due to how things are mapped. This is part of the "bad news" that Richard's answer discussed.