# How to check hard disk is Sata Device or it is IDE Device using c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, hardware, hard-drive

I have SATA Hard Disk, and I want to detect by C# windows form. I want to display that it is SATA or IDE drive. I am using following code but it always return IDE but its should be return SATA. So any one can help me to where I am wrong.

```
WqlObjectQuery q = new WqlObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive");
ManagementObjectSearcher res = new ManagementObjectSearcher(q);

foreach (ManagementObject o in res.Get())
 {
  string lblInterface= o["InterfaceType"].ToString();
 }
```

Comment: U can use [Drive Info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.aspx) Class. U can get the Information.

Answer (score 1):

According to the `Win32_DiskDrive` class [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394132%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), the possible values for `InterfaceType` are:

SCSI

HDC

IDE

USB

1394

Hence, you would not see SATA.

However, `Caption` property may contain extra information about the drive. You can parse it to find whether it contains ATA or SCSI.

Comment: ok, but which value is for SATA Drive. And it returs IDE, But I have SATA Drive.

Comment: Ok, it's not in the list of possible values, thus defaults to IDE?

Comment: This question may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362199/how-to-check-if-hard-drive-is-eide-or-sata-with-powershell

Comment: Thankx, but i am searching for C#.

Comment: It's the same underlying API.

Answer (score 1):

Check the `caption` property of `win32_DiskDrive` for the string ATA

From MSDN
[Caption](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394132%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
Data type: string
Access type: Read-only
Qualifiers: MaxLen (64), DisplayName ("Caption")
**Short description of the object**

```
foreach (ManagementObject o in res.Get())
{
     string sCaption = o["Caption"].ToString();
     if(sCaption.Contains("ATA"))
     {
          Console.WriteLine("SATA Drive");
          break;
     }
}
```

Comment: Brother are sure that every SATA Device's Caption contains  "ATA" string?